# Managing customer in Magento returns fatal error

Tags: magento-1.9, module, customer

I am using Magneto 1.9.3.2 and when i try to edit customer returns this massage:

> Fatal error: Declaration of
>   Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Attribute_Source_Website::getAllOptions()
>   must be compatible with
>   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table::getAllOptions($withEmpty
>   = true, $defaultValues = false) in /home/reprosty/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Source/Website.php
>   on line 34

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are running on PHP 7.x where method signature compatibility is strictly enforced. The only current version of Magento 1.x that supports PHP 7.x is 1.9.4.0 or patched previous versions.

If you're running a previous version and don't want to upgrade to 1.9.4.0 for some reason then the [Magento 1 PHP 7.2 patches are available here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2240)

Please refer to this also: https://inchoo.net/magento/magento-1-official-php-7-2-patches/